# Count property on tree structure (non-binary)

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree

I am implementing a tree Data structure in c# based (largely on [Dan Vanderboom's Generic implementation](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/)). I am now considering approach on handling a Count property which Dan does not implement.

The obvious and easy way would be to use a recursive call which Traverses the tree happily adding up nodes (or iteratively traversing the tree with a Queue and counting nodes if you prefer). It just  seems expensive. (I also may want to lazy load some of my nodes down the road).

I could maintain a count at the root node.  All children would traverse up to and/or hold a reference to the root, and update a internally settable count property on changes. This would push the iteration problem to when ever I want to break off a branch or clear all children below a given node. Generally less expensive, and puts the heavy lifting what I think will be less frequently called functions.

Seems a little brute force, and that usually means exception cases I haven't thought of yet, or bugs if you prefer.

Does anyone have an example of an implementation which keeps a count for an *Unbalanced and/or non-binary tree* structure rather than counting on the fly?  Don't worry about the lazy load, I am sure I can adjust the example to fit my specific needs.

Comment: Why not use a static variable and increment/decrement as needed?

Comment: Static variable would apply to all instances of my tree structure.

Comment: True (too many things on my mind at once).  Why not an instance variable then?

Comment: Why does a recursive call seem expensive?  That's the natural way to look at it in my opinion.

Comment: @Stanley thanks for your point.  I agree one can argue that recursive is an acceptable path.  It is just my view that recursion presents some risk, even if very small and unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your comments.  I didn't really want to invite debate, just wanted to see if anyone had a sample, which seems not to be the case.

I think the answer is there isn't a good sample available and I will need to do the work myself.

I've given each of you a +1 as you have all contributed to my conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a count property on the tree. In the method that adds nodes, increase the count and in the method that removes nodes, decrease the count.

Runtime = the time it takes to read a property.

Comment: In a Tree you can add Nodes to Nodes. How would the tree keep track of these?

Comment: Thanks @SamualDavis. Dave has pointed out exactly the complication that I am looking to solve.

Comment: You could have a node class that extends a tree class, and allow nodes to contain nodes. Each node class has a count property and the tree class also has a count property. Each time a node is added, the parent nodes count is increased by one, and the tree's count property is also increased by 1. This way you'd be able to tell how many direct descendents each node has, also how many are in the tree all together. If you want each node to hold knowledge of how many children it has however, my ideas would run short.

Comment: @SamuelDavis thanks.  You've described what I want to do. Gilfish's suggestion below is similar.  I like it.  I just want a sample implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking all about the nodes, and forgetting that there is a Tree class that controls access to the nodes. Your Tree class can have a Count property, and since Add and Remove are both exposed by the Tree class (they shouldn't be exposed by the nodes) you can always increment it and decrement it as the items are changed.

Comment: The Nodes should have an `Add()` method, how else do you descend the tree?

Comment: Thanks @TimC you are correct for a binary tree, but not for an unbalanced or non-binary tree.  ie.  You don't add folders to your "My Documents" folder at  "c:\".

Comment: That Add method should not be public. The tree needs to protect the nodes - they are an implementation detail of the tree and not something that the outside world should know anything about. There are a few ways of protecting that method, but the bottom line is that consumers using your tree should never be able to call Add on the nodes directly. The tree itself might, but nobody else.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I would be interested in seeing an example implementation.  The current implementation and example allows the setting of the parent property of a node.  Effectively adding a node .  Your premise would suggest that all move, copy, remove and setting of parents activity would be protected as well.

Comment: @Spevy You're correct. Anything which has to do with the management of the tree structure should go in the tree class. That's the point of having the tree class. If you just want a string of nodes, you can do that without creating a Tree class at all. There are lots of different ways to implement it, but the most common way I've seen is to give each node a key or id, then expose methods which take the parent key as a parameter - for example, AddChild(parentKey, childKey, childData).

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I appreciate the time you are spending. it seems like our experiences of unstructured trees are a little different. You indicate you've seen a few implementations, I would really like to learn from them if you can provide. Beyond the link above, I'll refer you to the W3C DOM Document Object Model or Microsoft's XMLNode object which are examples of an unstructured tree which allow nodes to mange themselves.

Comment: @Spevy You're probably right in that regard - when I talk about implementations I've seen, I mean in-the-wild solutions, not necessarily research definitions. You'll notice that DOM and MS XML don't provide any structural functions (Count, etc. aren't there). They're just loose collections of nodes. In your case, you want a stronger management pattern, closer to how a BST works. I've written these several times before, but I'm not sure there's a good "standard" example.

Answer (score 1):

Your Node class could keep a count of how many children it has, which it would update each time a node is added to or removed from it. Then to get the count for the root node (or any node, for that matter) you would just sum up the counts of all its children.

But to keep things simple, why not do as D Stanley suggests and just implement Count recursively?

Comment: @glilfish.  Thanks I considered that approach.  I would still have to traverse through each child to find the Children's children's childern... you get the idea.  Still traversing through the tree.

Comment: You wouldn't have to traverse through each child if each node cached off the number of children it had. The cached count would have to be updated each time a node's children collection was altered, of course, but then you would only have to look at the first level of children to get the count.

Comment: @gilfish If I understand you are suggesting the following.  Treat each node like a root node, with a count value of all descendants.  I will have to still maintain those counts up the tree if I add a child say 20 levels down.

Comment: @Spevy Ah, I see my error. Yes, my solution would require each child node to have a pointer to its parent, and then you would have to propagate the change all the way up to the root node.

Comment: Your solution isn't wrong.  It is along the lines of the design I contemplate above, I just think there is something I am overlooking.